# Prevent org export from expanding \ as $\backslash$

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When using the org's [`ox-koma-letter`](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/koma-letter-export.html), I'm having a problem with org exporting LaTeX commands expanding the leading `\` as `$\backslash$`.

Using the example letter ([from Romeo to Juliet](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/koma-letter-export.html)) on the orgmode.org site, if I change the closing section as follows:

```
* Yours truly,                                                      :closing:
#+LaTeX: \hspace{2em}  
Romeo of House Montague
```

But org's export to LaTeX is expanding the line with the `\hspace{2em}` command as:

```
\setkomavar{signature}{$\backslash$hspace\{2em\} Romeo of House Montague}
```

How do I prevent this?

[edited to specify precise environment in which issue is occurring.]

[edit 2: As of 20180702, the `org-koma-letter` Signature definition in `org-contrib` is:

```el
 ;; Signature.
 (let* ((heading-val
     (and (plist-get info :with-headline-opening)
      (org-string-nw-p
       (org-trim
        (org-export-data
         (org-koma-letter--get-tagged-contents 'closing)
         info)))))
    (signature (org-string-nw-p (plist-get info :signature)))
    (signature-scope (funcall check-scope 'signature)))
   (and (or (and signature signature-scope)
    heading-val)
    (not (and (eq scope 'global) heading-val))
    (format "\\setkomavar{signature}{%s}\n"
        (if signature-scope signature heading-val))))
```

Which still produces the same issue. ]

Comment: Does not happen with emacs-version 26.1 and `org-version` 9.1.6. What versions of emacs and org-mode do you have? Does the same problem occur with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I've edited the question above with more detail.  I've just tried it with `emacs -Q` just adding the `ox-koma-letter` export code, and I get the same behaviour. I'm using emacs 26.1 and org-version 9.1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can replace the [Section `;; Signature`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/contrib/lisp/ox-koma-letter.el#L818-L832) in function `org-koma-letter--build-settings` with the following code.
I essentially removed `org-export-data` from there.

```el
 ;; Signature.
 (let* ((heading-val
     (and (plist-get info :with-headline-opening)
      (org-string-nw-p
       (org-trim
        ;; (org-export-data
         (or (org-koma-letter--get-tagged-contents 'closing) "")
        ;; info)
                ))))
    (signature (org-string-nw-p (plist-get info :signature)))
    (signature-scope (funcall check-scope 'signature)))
   (and (or (and signature signature-scope)
    heading-val)
    (not (and (eq scope 'global) heading-val))
    (format "\\setkomavar{signature}{%s}\n"
        (if signature-scope signature heading-val))))
```

They use the [translator for the headlines `org-koma-letter-headline`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/contrib/lisp/ox-koma-letter.el#L615-L628) to extract the `:opening:` headline and put its stuff into `org-koma-letter-special-contents`. `org-koma-letter--get-tagged-contents` retrieves the opening from there.
I have the impression that `org-koma-letter-headline` already gets the translated headline `contents` and translating it again with `org-export-data` is a bad idea.

Comment: Is there a good way of doing this (i.e. replacing the Signature bit) without just editing the org-koma-letter file itself? E.g. of programmatically replacing it in `.emacs`?

Comment: @emacsomancer I've already posted a bug report and the problem is already fixed in the development version of orgmode. ... Should be available via melpa very soon.

Comment: Cheers!  I'll just wait for the fix to come down via Melpa.

Comment: @emacsomancer Nicolas Goaziou notified me about a small problem in [his answer to my buf-fix proposal](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-06/msg00317.html). The case when `org-koma-letter--get-tagged-contents` must be handled separately. I've corrected the above bugfix in that regard. I've tested the corrected version with org files containing a `:closing:` and org files not containing any `:closing:`. Looks like it runs flawless.

Comment: I've noticed that as of `org-contrib` of 20180702, the signature bit in `org-koma-letter` still has error-producing `org-export-data` lines included (see OP edit). I assumed the fix would have rolled out by now.